# How do I work around with the selected range?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am kinda new to Google apps script and I'm trying to make a function in google spreadsheet that moves a selected range by a row down, repeating it every first day of the month.
I typed down some codes after a little bit of researching.. I don't know if I am correct.

```
function rowdown(input)
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(..., spreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NO_BORDERS)
```

How should I use 'input' to make paste destination?

I want to know how to work with the selected ranges correctly.

Comment: `insertRowAbove()`

Answer (score 0):

This set of functions will create an input dialog and allow you to enter data into a cell of your choice in the active sheet via a modeless dialog box.  It will also allow you to continue entering data into the next cell below the one that you first selected.

```
function getMyInput() {
  var html='<style>input[type=button]{margin:5px;}#pnxt,#cls{display:none;}</style><br />Give Me Some Input: <input type="text" id="txt1" /><br />Select a cell to put it into and then click Paste Button:<br /><input type="button" value="Paste" onClick="pasteItDude();" /><br /><input id="pnxt" type="button" value="Paste Into Next Cell Below" onClick="pasteNext();" />';
  html+='<br /><input id="cls" type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  html+='<script>function pasteItDude(){var val=document.getElementById(\"txt1\").value;google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){document.getElementById(\"pnxt\").style.display=\"inline\";document.getElementById(\"cls\").style.display=\"inline\";}).pasteItMan(val);}';
  html+='function pasteNext(){var val=document.getElementById(\"txt1\").value;google.script.run.pasteNext(val);}console.log(\"My Code\");</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Give me some data.');
}

function pasteItMan(txt) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getActiveCell().setValue(txt);
  return;
}

function pasteNext(txt) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getActiveCell().offset(1,0).activate();
  ss.getActiveCell().setValue(txt);
  return;
}
```

It's not the easiest way to create a dialog but it is versatile.  For more information here's some references.

- [Client To Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)-This is the most empowering for new programmers
- [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)